# C++ String to double conversion in scientific notation

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I want to convert a given string into double without converting the value into decimal, if the string is in scientific format.

That is 1.23e1 should be saved as 1.23e1 and not as 12.3.

I checked stringstream, strtod, boost::lexical_cast and other methods
but all of these convert 1.23e1 into 12.3.

Is there a way that so that 1.23e1 can be saved as 1.23e1 instead of 12.3??

Comment: It seems that you don't quite undertstand what a *number* is. 12.3 and 1.23e1 are *the same number*.

Comment: yeah 12.3 and 1.23e1 are the same, but i want to keep it as 1.23e1 to use it for further operations.
So is that possible to convert the string 1.23e1 into a float without converting to decimal??

Comment: 12.3 and 1.23e1 are the same. What's the difference when using first or second in operations? none... It's representation in double is the same, only representation for humans **on the screen** is different...

Answer (score 5):

You're confusing the value with its representations.

12.3, 1.23e1, 0.123e2 and 123.0e-1 are all representations of the same value. They will also be stored in a double exactly the same representation, whichever one you input. The IEEE-754 format defines how a value is represented in a double-precision floating-point format. It's a binary format that looks nothing like "1.23e1".

So, ignore any perceived representation issues on your *input*. All you need to do is ensure that the *output representation* (i.e. when converting the double to a string representation of the value) is in the format you want. To do this, look at [std::scientific](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed):

```
double a = 12.3;
std::cout << std::scientific << a << "\n";
```

Output:

```
1.230000e+01
```

You can also manipulate the [precision](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision) to obtain more or fewer digits:

```
std::cout << std::scientific << std::setprecision(2) << a << "\n";
```

Output:

```
1.23e+01
```